# How to upload JPEG / PDF file to mongodb using mongocxx/bsoncxx drivers (C++)

Tags: c++, json, mongodb

I am trying to do an application, to upload files to my data base. Using C++ and mongoDB.
I am at the point of uploading the file to the mongodb, but database recieves only `fs.files` the filename and `fs.chunks` chuncks are empty.

Contents of fs.files

```
_id:5f39fda08056e04d8a2d4356
length:0
chunkSize:261120
uploadDate:2020-08-17T03:46:40.978+00:00
filename:"/home/mycg/Downloads/sample.pdf"
```

fs.chunks are empty indeed.

Should I be preparing my file somehow or include specific options before sending it? **fp** is just a filepath retrieved by `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`

```
void MainWindow::on_push_button_clicked()
{
    QString bri_file_path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Upload a file", "C://");
    uploader->upload_file(bri_file_path);
}
```

```
void Uploader::upload_file(QString fp)
{
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{"/connection"}};

       auto db = conn["files"];
       auto bucket = db.gridfs_bucket();
       auto uploader = bucket.open_upload_stream(fp.toStdString());
       auto result = uploader.close();

}
```

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: 1.[mongocxx](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-v3/)
2.[mongocxx Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver)

Comment: Where does it talk about gridfs?